# Creating video conferencing example in jitsi-meet

Tags: jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am exploring WebRTC based solutions for video conferencing. Have found Jitsi to be one of the prominent candidate to look around from various frameworks.

**Example Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <?php 
        $webroot =  '/openemr-local';
     ?>
    <script src="<?php echo $webroot ?>/jitsi-meet/libs/lib-jitsi-meet.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $webroot ?>/jitsi-meet/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $webroot ?>/jitsi-meet/libs/strophe/strophe.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $webroot ?>/jitsi-meet/libs/strophe/strophe.disco.min.js?v=1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $webroot ?>/jitsi-meet/example.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="jitsi-test">
            <span>Join Meeting Name</span><input type="text" id="meetingroom" name="meetingroom"/>
            <button id="join" name="join" onclick="joinMeeting()">Join Me</button>
            <button id="disconnect" name="disconnect" onclick="unload()">Disconnect</button>
        </div>  
        <div id="video-container">
        </div>     
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using `example.js` from [Jitsi-meet Git Hub Example](https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/example/example.js) with below changes:

```
const options = {
    hosts: {
        domain: 'beta.meet.jit.si',

        muc: 'conference.beta.meet.jit.si', // FIXME: use XEP-0030
        focus: 'focus.beta.meet.jit.si',
    },
    bosh:'//beta.meet.jit.si/http-bind', // FIXME: use xep-0156 for that
    // The name of client node advertised in XEP-0115 'c' stanza
    clientNode: 'http://jitsi.org/jitsimeet'
};
```

Video gets launched on the browser bu I am not able to get

1. Connection Callback -- `onConnectionSuccess` never gets called. I did put 
   debugger there.
2. Getting error on console 
   `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://beta.meet.jit.si/http-bind' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`

**EDIT:**

After adding `https:` to `bosh:'//beta.meet.jit.si/http-bind'`. The CORS error is gone and also onConnectionSuccess is working fine.

Still, Need some pointers on working Conference example.

I am trying to achieve something similar to below example:
[jitsi-meet custom GUI](https://community.jitsi.org/t/jitsi-dev-jitsi-meet-video-conferences-with-a-custom-gui/12753)

Comment: Well, After adding 'https:' to `bosh:'//beta.meet.jit.si/http-bind'`. The CORS error is gone and also `onConnectionSuccess ` is working fine.

Comment: As I know, you should install jitsi on your own server, if you want to customize it: https://jitsi.org/news/new-tutorial-installing-jitsi-meet-on-your-own-linux-server/

Comment: Please have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63991215/8810941.