# Cannot join the conference created by lib-jitsi-meet in a headless browser

Tags: puppeteer, jitsi-meet

I'm trying to create a conference using `lib-jitsi-meet` in a headless Chrome instance using Puppeteer and join it using the Jitsi External API (iframe API) from another browser. Currently, I can create a meeting in a headless browser, but I can't join the created meeting from another browser. When I tried so, another new conference with the same name is created and I'm the only participant in it.

Can someone provide me with helpful advice on this problem? You can view the [index.html](https://jitsi-liveroom.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/index.html) and [example.js](https://jitsi-liveroom.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/example.js).

Thanks in advance

Puppeteer code

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
headless: false,
product: 'chrome',
// args: ['wait-for-browser'],
defaultViewport: { width: 1600, height: 1600 },
});
const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
await page.goto("https://jitsi-liveroom.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/index.html")
```

Comment: Interesting usage! What's your use-case if I may ask? Do you want to record meetings?

Comment: We wanted to use jitsi to create a video chat app, without messing with the Jitsi source code. Since there is no server-side API for Jitsi, we emulate using a headless browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the following `options` object as a param to the `JitsiConnection` in `example.js`, I was able to avoid CORS errors and join multiple users to the same conference.

```js
const [meetingName,setMeetingName] = useState("")

const options = {
   hosts: {
      domain: 'meet.jit.si',
      muc: 'conference.meet.jit.si', 
      focus: 'focus.meet.jit.si',
   }, 
   externalConnectUrl: 'https://meet.jit.si/http-pre-bind', 
   enableP2P: true, 
   p2p: { 
      enabled: true, 
      preferH264: true, 
      disableH264: true, 
      useStunTurn: true,
   }, 
   useStunTurn: true, 
   bosh: `https://meet.jit.si/http-bind?room=${meetingName}`, 
   websocket: 'wss://meet.jit.si/xmpp-websocket', 
   clientNode: 'http://jitsi.org/jitsimeet', 
}
```

Comment: From the github page of lib-jitsi-meet, it says that bosh is deprecated and we should be using serviceUrl to specify the BOSH or Websocket URL. https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/API.md#installation

Comment: Also, it won't work unless the room name is provided as a query parameter, but didn't found it in the docs but deep down in an old thread in the jitsi community forum.

Comment: Am i supposed to replace all the meet.jit.si's with the domain name of my own  jitsi server?

Comment: @gandalf yes, you need to

Comment: I found it a bit harder than that, which is why I created an example: https://github.com/solarkraft/lib-jitsi-meet-demo/blob/master/src/JitsiMeet.ts